# Windows Share Unavailable when Accessing from Wifi

Tags: windows, networking, router, wifi, share

We are running a small LAN in our Company using a Cisco Router. Attached to this Router is QNAP NAS providing Access to Data via Windows Shares (we all use Windows 7 Computers). As the Router does not provide WiFi Access, we attached an old D-Link Router (that works fine) and use it as an Access Point. Everything is working fine (including Printing on the Network Printers, Internet Access, even Accessing other Windows PC in the Network) when accessing the network via WiFi. However it is not possible to access the windows shares on the QNAP any more. We allays get the error that the Network Path can not be found/is unavailable.
We can see any reason why this is not working. Any ideas what the problem is and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance you have the D-Link attached via its WAN port? If so, you may consider taking a closer look to see if the D-Link has a "wireless access point" mode, which will probably be more appropriate for your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Unfortunately the DIR-635 does not have a AP Mode. However I configured it to work as an AP according to the manual provided by D-Link. Besides the Windows Shares Issue the AP works very well. I could imagine that this is some DNS or WINS problem here but I do not really have any idea how to troubleshoot the problem any further.

Comment: How is the D-Link connected to the rest of your network?

Comment: Sorry did forget to specify this. It is connected using a LAN Port on the D-Link using an RJ45 wire directly to a LAN port on the Cisco Router.

Comment: Can the wireless clients successfully ping the QNAP - by name vs. IP address?

Comment: IP Works fine but Name does not. Looking at the protocol by wireshark, it seems the query for the share name goes out to the wrong address (from my pc 192.168.1.20 to 192.168.1.255 and there is no server that has this 255 address). Thanks again I really appreciate your help here!

Comment: I think I was able to find the problem. Using WiFi my computer sends the NBNS Request to 192.168.1.255 and does not receive a reply. Using LAN it receives a reply from 192.168.1.19 (the Ip of the QNAP) and everything works. Now I have no idea what exactly this means or what to do about it.

Comment: Wow thanks again for you help. I am not that far that I can access the shares by using the IP address of the QNAP instead of the name. This is a really good first solution. However it would be good to gain more insight why the QNAP does not respond to the NBNS requests and how this can be fixed (may be also with a client side setting) as the QNAP's IP address might change from time to time. If you have any further thoughts on this, that would be very cool. Anyway thanks for getting me that far!

Comment: Okay so the next workaround was to add an entry to the windows hosts file (192.168.1.19 qnapdata) and the shares work fine. I still would love to figure out why the QNAP does not respond to the NBNS request and if i can do something about this. Anyways I will mark this question as solved for now but i anyone has further input, please let me know.

Comment: 192.168.1.255 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 would make that the IP broadcast address. That can explain a few things. From you descriptions, it looks like the wireless may not be allowing the IP broadcasts to forward/bridge from the wireless to the wired portion, which may be what you are facing. If you can live with the host file entry/entries, then that can work vs. further troubleshooting why the wireless will not allow the forwarding of IP broadcasts onto the wired or something along those line.

Comment: Thanks again for the support. I think I can live with the host file entry for now. Troubleshooting the Ip Broadcast Issue is probably a different question anyway and I will first try to look into that my self. Thanks and have a very nice day! Thomas

Comment: Cool... Glad it worked out for you.